# THREEJS - Shadow artifact - IOS devices

Tags: ios, three.js, webgl

I have a weird shadow artifact only on IOS devices as shown below. The shadows work fine on desktop and android. It is not a bias problem, nor a self shadowing problem (although it does look like it) since i know the normals are correct and there are no double faces. It occurs only on IOS devices (tested iPhone 6, 8, 10 and ipad air 1, 2). Has anyone ever faced similar problem (outside of bias and self shadowing)?

**Edit:** for the sake of clarity to others who might face the same problem. the light direction is from front of house looking at back of the house (positioned at opposite direction of where the screenshot is taken and facing towards the backyard), Hence the roof at back side (the taken screenshot) should be completely in shadow. However as you can see in the picture, the shadow on ground is correct, but the shadow on roof is cut with only some sections being in shadow.

**Live demo** You can see the problem on here (problem occurs on IOS device only): https://expivi.expivi.net/product/house-demo (I will apply the solution in a few days and will state here whenever the problem is not visible anymore)

**Solution** as answered below the problem comes from Threejs default value for shadow cameras. Having set the shadow camera's near plane at 0.5, assuming large metrics.

[image]

Comment: Put more detail about source code  ....

Comment: Its 70K line of source of proprietary software. And its not a coding problem, get some knowledge about the subject before down-voting a question. I am simply asking whether anyone has faced the same problem.

Comment: Maybe draw indicate red line because this render look nice.

Answer (score 1):

Threejs seems to set the near value of camera of shadowmap at 0.5 by default. The combination of low floating point precision on IOS and metrics we are using causes the problem.
Setting the lightObject.shadow.camera.near = 0.01; solves the problem.

Comment: Thank you for share it is a good practice to give solution for problem !

Comment: @SiamakM.Mirzaie Would you please update your post and make it clear what the issue is, and also provide a live example so the issue can be duplicated?

Comment: Yes, i have updated the picture and added additional info to the problem.

Comment: If you would like the three.js devs to have a look at this, you can file a post on the three.js site, but that will require you to create a 50-line program to replicate the issue.